# How to do full right outer join in kdb?

Tags: join, outer-join, kdb

I have these two tables.

```
tab1:([]col1:`abc`def`ghi;col2:2 4 6);
tab2:([]col1:`def`ghi`ghi`rrr;col3:5 10 11 15);
```

I want to keep everything in the right table but duplicated the col1 to match the col1 in tab2. The closest I found is ij

```
tab2 ij 1! tab1

col1 col3 col2  
--------------
def  5    4   
ghi  10   6    
ghi  11   6
```

However, I would like to produce this result:

```
col1 col3 col2
--------------
abc       2
def  5    4   
ghi  10   6   
ghi  11   6
```

If there is other values in col1 in tab2, I am not interested to put that to result table: like I don't want `rrr in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
q)uj[select from tab1 where not col1 in exec col1 from tab2;tab2 ij 1!tab1]
col1 col2 col3
--------------
abc  2        
def  4    5   
ghi  6    10  
ghi  6    11
```

Here we apply union to a) everything from `tab1` which is not present in `tab2` and b) everything which is present in both `tab1` **and** `tab2`.

Not sure we can call this *full outer right join* because we don't want to include *all* records from tab2 (`rrr` in this case) but this is a terminology problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
q){x,flip y}/[tab1 lj `col1 xgroup tab2]
col1 col2 col3
------------------
abc  2    `long$()
def  4    5
ghi  6    10
ghi  6    11
```

Not heavily tested but it's a starting point!

EDIT: actually, it's a little more subtle than that. The flip will cause problems when there's a blank list in col3, the example above just so happens to avoid that by chance.

You'd probably need something like this to catch edge-cases:

```
q){x,$[0=count f:flip y;enlist first each y;f]}/[();tab1 lj `col1 xgroup tab2]
col1 col2 col3
--------------
abc  2
def  4    5
ghi  6    10
ghi  6    11
```